# Prove: a set of vectors $K$ is linearly dependent iff a vector is linear combination of the others

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove: a set of vectors $K$ is linearly dependent iff  a vector is linear combination of the others.

Let: $\alpha_1k_1 + \alpha_2k_2+...\alpha_nk_n = 0$

Then, There must be $\alpha_i \ne 0$. Therefore,

$$\alpha_1k_1 + \alpha_2k_2 + \alpha_{i-1}k_{i-1} + \alpha_{i+1}k_{i+1}+...+ \alpha_nk_n = -\alpha_ik_i.$$

Then,
$${\alpha_1 \over -\alpha_i}k_1 + {\alpha_2 \over -\alpha_i}k_2+...+{\alpha_n \over -\alpha_i}k_n = k_i$$

Indeed, $k_i$ is a linear combination of the other vectors.

My question is:
Is that answering the **iff** condition?

Comment: This answers the *if* and not the *only if*.

Comment: You need to show that if a vector is a linear combination of the others, then the collection is linearly dependent.

Comment: @copper.hat, isn't it just reading the current proof from bottom to top?

Comment: @SuperStamp  Yes, just read backwards.  All your implications go both ways.

Comment: Two questions: (1) is it a rigorous proof, I if I write "read backward to prove other direction"? (2) Instead, I could prove the _only if_ as @SamiBenRomdhane mentioned. Which means: if the set is linearly independent then non of the vector is linear combination of the others. Right?

Comment: @SuperStamp: It depends on your audience. Instructing your reader to read the steps in reverse can work, but it is completely unambiguous and less commanding to just establish a sequence of equivalences.

Comment: @SuperStamp: formally, the reverse direction is *no* valid proof, but it is very easy to transform it into one.

Comment: BTW, the above can easily be reinforced a little as follows: a *well-ordered* set of vectors (for example, a finite or countable infinite one) is linearly dependent iff there is one vector linearly dependent *on the preceeding ones*. This can be pretty handy when dealing with some exercises.

Comment: Your proof, as written, is incorrect. Why do you have 

$${\alpha_1 \over -\alpha_1}k_1 + {\alpha_2 \over -\alpha_2}k_2+\cdots+{\alpha_n \over -\alpha_n}k_n = k_i$$ 

It is very rare that

$$-k_1 -k_2-\cdots -k_n = k_i$$

Perhaps your mean

$${\alpha_1 \over -\alpha_i}k_1 + {\alpha_2 \over -\alpha_i}k_2+\cdots+{\alpha_n \over -\alpha_i}k_n = k_i$$

Comment: @FlybyNight, it was a typo(s). I'll correct that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

Assume that there exist $a_i \in \mathbb{K}$ for which $a_1{\bf v}_1+\cdots+a_n{\bf v}_n = {\bf 0}$, where not all $a_i$ are zero.

Then, as you say, there exists an $a_k \neq 0$, and we can write

$${\bf v}_k = -\frac{1}{a_k}(a_1{\bf v}_1+\cdots + a_{k-1}{\bf v}_{k-1}+a_{k+1}{\bf v}_{k+1}+\cdots+a_n{\bf v}_n)$$

Hence ${\bf v}_k$ is a linear combination of the other ${\bf v}_i$.

---

Assume that ${\bf v}_k$ is a linear combination of the other ${\bf v}_i$. In that case, there exist $\lambda_j \in \mathbb{K}$ for which
$${\bf v}_k = \lambda_1{\bf v}_1 + \cdots + \lambda_{k-1}{\bf v}_{k-1}+\lambda_{k+1}{\bf v}_{k+1}+\cdots + \lambda_n{\bf v}_n$$

Putting ${\bf v}_k=\sum_{i \neq k} \lambda_i{\bf v}_i$ into $a_1{\bf v}_1+\cdots + a_n{\bf v}_n$ shows that $\lambda_j = -a_j$ gives

$$a_1{\bf v}_1+\cdots+a_n{\bf v}_n = {\bf 0}$$

---